# Appending new information and rethrowing errors in nested functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to implement an error handling that when a function raises an error, the calling function should catch that error and add some information to it, in order to make the problem easier to understand. In the example below, I try to explain my doubts. The `first` and `second` functions are called by `third`, and each one of them generates different errors, with different information. I would like the `third` function to be able to catch these errors and attach some information to them (the way the example is currently implemented I lose the information that `first` and `second` attached to the error).

```
class FirstError extends Error {
    constructor(msg, num) {
        super(msg);
        this.num = num;
    }
}

class SecondError extends Error {
    constructor(msg, str) {
        super(msg);
        this.str = str;
    }
}

class ThirdError extends Error {
    constructor(msg, arg) {
        super(msg);
        this.arg = arg;
    }
}

function first(num) {
    throw new FirstError('First error', num);
}

function second(num) {
    throw new SecondError('Second error', num.toString());
}

function third(fn) {
    try {
        fn(25);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new ThirdError('Third error', fn);
    }
}

try {
    third(first);
    third(second);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(error instanceof Error);
    console.log(error instanceof FirstError);
    console.log(error instanceof SecondError);
    console.log(error instanceof ThirdError);
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log(error.stack);
}
```

I also understand that I could test the instances of the error received on `third`, as the example below. However, as I will have several functions returning errors, this approach would be uninteresting as I would be left with too many tests and would have to update the third function with each new type of error added.

```
function third(fn) {
    try {
        fn(25);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof FirstError) {
            throw new ThirdError('Third error', fn);
        } else if (error instanceof SecondError) {
            throw new ThirdError('Third error', fn);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the original error to the ThirdError. Then you can access that error, for example

```
...
class ThirdError extends Error {
    constructor(msg, ...args) {
        super(msg);
        this.arg = args[0];
        this.innerError = args.slice(1);
    }
}

...
function third(fn) {
    try {
        fn(25);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new ThirdError('Third error', fn, error);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ThirdError: Third error
  ...,
  innerError: [
    FirstError: First error
        ... {
      num: 25
    }
  ]
}
...
```